# dynamically change an image via c# script in Xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a cross platform app which I need to show a set of images when the user clic in a button, so, I put these image files named as "img000.png" to "img029.png" in a folder in the PCL solution and make al these images as "EmbeddedResource", after,I fill a List with all these images and its work fine at now, i.e. the image is shown like I want, but when I click in the button to show the next image in the list the image don't go to the next.

I have this:

```cs
//...
public class ImageSetPage : BasePage
// BasePage encapsule a ContentPage...
{
    private string directory = "MyApp.Assets.";
    private int idx = 0;
    protected StackLayout _mainLayout;
    protected StackLayout _buttonStack;
    protected Image _btnPrevI;
    protected Label _displayName; 
    protected Image _btnNestI;
    protected Image _image;
    protected List<Image> _Images;

    public ImageSetPage()
    {
        this._Images = getImages();
        var prevI_Tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        prevI_Tap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            onClick("pvi");
        };
        var nextI_Tap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        nextI_Tap.Tapped += (s, e) =>
        {
            onClick("nti");
        };

        /// begin layout
        base.Title = "set of Images";

        this._mainLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0)
        };

        this._btnPrevI = new Image()
        {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource(directory+"prevbtn.png")
        };
         _btnPrevI.GestureRecognizers.Add(prevI_Tap);

        this._displayName = new Label()
        {
            Style = Device.Styles.SubtitleStyle,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            TextColor = Color.White,
       };

       this._btnNextI = new Image()
       {
            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
            Source = ImageSource.FromResource(directory + "nextbtn.png")
        };
        _btnNextI.GestureRecognizers.Add(nextI_Tap);
        this._buttonStack.Children.Add(_btnPrevI);
        this._buttonStack.Children.Add(_displayName);
        this._buttonStack.Children.Add(_btnNextI);
        this._mainLayout.Children.Add(_buttonStack);
        FillImage(idx);
        this._mainLayout.Children.Add(this._image);
        this.Content = this._mainLayout;
    }

    private void FillImage(int i)
    {
        this._displayName.Text = "Image n# " + FillWithZeroes(i);
        // [EDIT 1] cemented these lines ...
        // this._image = null;
        // mi = _images[i];
        // this._image = mi;
        // [EDIT 2] the new try
        string f = directory + "imgs.img0" + FillWithZeroes(i) + ".png";
        this._image = new Image() {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Soruce = ImageSource.FromResource(f)
        };
        // In this way the image show and don't change when click
        // this Fking* code is a big S_OF_THE_B*
        // The Xamarin and the C# is brothers of this FKing* code
    }

    private void onClick(string v)
    {
        string vw = v;
        if (vw.Equals("pvi")) idx--;
        if (vw.Equals("nti")) idx++;
        if (idx <=  0) idx = 29;
        if (idx >= 29) idx = 0;
        FillImage(idx);
        vw = "";
    }

    private string FillWithZeroes(int v)
    {
        string s = v.ToString();
        string r = "";
        if (s.Length == 1) { r = "0" + s; } else { r = s; }
        return r;
    }

    // to fill a list of Images with files in a PCL folder
    private List<Image> getImages() 
    {
        string directory = "MyApp.Assets.";
        List<Image> imgCards = new List<Image>();
        int c = 0;
        for (c = 0; c < 30;c++) {
            string f = directory + "imgs.img0" + FillWithZeroes(c) + ".png";
            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(f);
            imgCards.Add(img);
        }            
        return imgCards;
    }
    // ...
}
```

but the image don't change, i.e. change, like I see in debug, but don't show in the Layout when I click in the buttons.
Maybe I'm doing it wrong.
Can someone here help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Image is a UI widget.  You don't really want to store a List<Image> in memory.  You should only need one Image to represent the Image being displayed, then in your FillImage() method you can just set the Source of that Image to the next/prev png

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I try it and nothing, the image don't change in the app running, I will put a edit in the thread to represent what I do.

Comment: you don't need to create a new Image, just update the source of the existing image, like "this._image.Source =ImageSource.FromResource(f);".  Does your label update?  You may need to force the update to happen on the UI Thread

Comment: I try this but the image remains the same which is the first image created when the application run, i.e. the "img000.png" and when I click it don't change to the next.

Comment: Are you sure that onClick is getting called when you tap the buttons?  Also try wrapping the UI update in BeginInvokeOnMainThread: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/

Comment: yes, because the text in the _displayName object change according to the "idx" variable

Comment: I Solved this question, I got the images changing using SkiaSharp with a SKCanvasView, thanks for all!